# How to convert a pair of second degree conic equations into a Polynomial of fourth degree?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given two second degree conic equations:
$$ax^2+by^2+cx+dy+e=0$$
and
$$fx^2+gy^2+hx+iy+j=0$$
[All coefficients are real]

To solve these equation for $x$ and $y$ a direct substitution yields a polynomial of fourth degree in $x$ (or $y$) as:
$$kx^4+lx^3+mx^2+nx+o=0$$
Is there any easier way to evaluate the coefficients of fourth degree Polynomial $(k,l,m,n,o)$ in $x$ (or $y$) in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$, $g$, $h$, $i$, $j$.

Comment: "easier" than what? Which 4th degree polynomial are we talking about? Just the product of the two you have?

Comment: easier than a direct substitution of one variable into the second equation

Answer (score 1):

Consider your two polynomials as polynomials $A(y),B(y)$ with coefficients that are polynomials in $x$, and compute the *resultant* of the two polynomials $A(y),B(y)$. That will give you the polynomial in $x$ that you want. You can calculate the resultant using the *Sylvester determinant*. Information about these two concepts is widely available on the web and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

$$g(ax^2+by^2+cx+dy+e)=0$$

$$-b(fx^2+gy^2+hx+iy+j)=0$$

Sum two equations and collect y in one side. ($y^2$ term will be zero  )

$$y= \frac{(bf-ga)x^2+(bh-gc)x+(bj-ge)}{gd-bi}=\frac{(bf-ga)}{gd-bi}x^2+\frac{(bh-gc)}{gd-bi}x+\frac{(bj-ge)}{gd-bi}$$  and then put in any of equation that you gave and you will get the coefficients of fourth degree Polynomial.